# What is the best way to notify all connected clients about changes on the server?

Tags: php, android

I am working on a small client-server project. The front-end is an Android application and the back-end is written in PHP. There is going to be several clients (10+-) that are going to manipulate the data in the server database. Those changes should be immediately reflected to all connected devices.

My question is, should I use sockets so the server will send the updated data to all connected devices once something gets updated or should rather a device be responsible for checking for updates on the server? If so, what would be the best way to do it? Should each row in the database have an update times-tamp and I always fetch all rows whose time-stamp is bigger than the time-stamp of the last update on the device.

Comment: i use a middleware (redis db) to share sessions between node.js and php. i use the `ws` library in node.js to build a small, lightweight push server, but process all client data in a php rest endpoint. i would highly advise against attempting websockets in php. when a socket attempts to send to a connection in a close state in php, the php script will hang, so with php, its battle against the probability that will happen, and in production, it will happen multiple time per day. the php send updates to the node server, and node server push to the clients that respond to a ping

Answer (score 0):

I think push notification the best solution for this task. And of course need to have timestamp of last changes in database and android client.